# How do I get a list of commands starting with a certain key (combo) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I can use `C-h c` (`describe-key-briefly`) and type a key combination and it will return me the function bound to it. But I'd also like to type only a *prefix* of a key combination and have it list and describe all functions bound to key sequences starting with it, like "all bound keys starting with `C-x`".

Comment: `C-h b` will give you *all* the current bindings...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do the key combo then C-h.  For your example of C-x, do C-x C-h.  This also works with sub-maps, e.g. C-x r C-h to see everything under C-x r

Comment: Awesome, I never knew this.  Not at all obvious, though.  Almost nothing in emacs is obvious.

Comment: Yeah, the section of the manual that describes this in detail is not very obvious.  Reading, what a waste of time!

Comment: You can also use `F1` instead of `C-h` (and indeed there's an instance where you can only use `F1` -- [see duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330510/show-emacs-keybindings-which-start-with-a-particular-key))

Answer (score 1):

It is also not the case that every prefix key works this way (follow it with <kbd>C-h</kbd> to see the bindings).

Here are two additional resources that can help:

- Command `describe-keymap`, in [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). But to use it you need to have the keymap available (e.g. as the value of a variable, such as `ctl-x-map`). Unlike just using <kbd>C-h v</kbd> on a keymap variable, the output is human readable.
- [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) [key completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).  Just type the prefix key, then hit `S-TAB`. Buffer `*Completions*` shows you all possible completions: the keys plus their associated commands (or `...` if they are themselves prefix keys).  For multiple-level prefix keys (e.g. <kbd>C-x r</kbd>) the candidates include prefix keys (e.g. prefix key <kbd>r</kbd> to partially complete prefix key <kbd>C-x</kbd>).  You can navigate up and down the keymap hierarchy this way.  And you can cycle among candidates and hit <kbd>C-M-RET</kbd> on any to see their complete help.