# Show Emacs keybindings which start with a particular key

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845934/emacs-print-key-binding-for-a-command-or-list-all-key-bindings), but my question is different. I'd like to know how to view key-bindings in Emacs which *start* with a particular key. I'd like to bind `f2`, but would like to know what it's currently bound to. Pressing `C-h` `m` prompts for the key sequence. Entering `f2` here results in Emacs waiting for me to complete the chain, as `f2` alone does nothing. How can I view all key-bindings which *start* with `f2`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

<kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>

In general, typing <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>C-h</kbd> after any prefix-binding will list all the bindings using that prefix:

> `describe-prefix-bindings` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `help.el`.
>
> Describe the bindings of the prefix used to reach this command.
>   The prefix described consists of all but the last event
>   of the key sequence that ran this command.

<kbd>F1</kbd> is the more reliable of the two (but only *very* slightly so), as detailed by the following documentation excerpts.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Misc Help")` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

> You can get a list of subcommands for a particular prefix key by typing `C-h` (`describe-prefix-bindings`) after the prefix key. (There are a few prefix keys for which this does not work--those that provide their own bindings for `C-h`.  One of these is `<ESC>`, because `<ESC> C-h` is actually `C-M-h`, which marks a defun.)

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Keys")` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

> Typing the help character (`C-h` or `<F1>`) after a prefix key displays a list of the commands starting with that prefix.  The sole exception to this rule is `<ESC>`: `<ESC> C-h` is equivalent to `C-M-h`, which does something else entirely.  You can, however, use `<F1>` to display a list of commands starting with `<ESC>`.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Help")` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

> `C-h` or `<F1>` means "help" in various other contexts as well.  For
>   instance, you can type them after a prefix key to view a list of the
>   keys that can follow the prefix key.  (A few prefix keys don't support
>   `C-h` in this way, because they define other meanings for it, but they
>   all support `<F1>` for help.)

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Key Binding Conventions")` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

> Don't bind `C-h` following any prefix character (including `C-c`).
>   If you don't bind `C-h`, it is automatically available as a help character for listing the subcommands of the prefix character.