# View all bindings starting with the `C-x r` prefix key?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a list of commands starting with a certain key (combo) in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282100/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-commands-starting-with-a-certain-key-combo-in-emacs)

For example, there're 3 commands like <kbd>C-x r i</kbd>, <kbd>C-x r s</kbd>, <kbd>C-x r b</kbd>

Does anyone have ideas about how to view all these commands starts with <kbd>C-x r</kbd> in emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just type <kbd>C-h</kbd> right after the prefix key: <kbd>C-x r C-h</kbd>